# Passing time from my function to data() time: in vuejs

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, methods

I have this method function that show me the duration of audio file but i don't know how to pass the value from checkMp3SizeAndDuration of time to data() {return { time: '' } }

Here's the code:

```
data () { 
    return {    
      time: ''
    }
  },   

methods: {  
checkMp3SizeAndDuration () {  

      const files = document.getElementById('file').files
      const file = files[0] 
      const reader = new FileReader()
      const audio = document.createElement('audio')
     
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        audio.src = e.target.result 
        let time = '' 
        audio.onloadedmetadata = () => {
          const seconds  = audio.duration
          const duration = moment.duration(seconds, 'seconds') 
          const hours = duration.hours()
          if (hours > 0) { time = `${hours}:` } 
          time = `${ duration.minutes()  }:${duration.seconds()}`  
          console.log(time) <-- Example time log: 3:51
          this.time = time // Don't work here..
        } 
        audio.addEventListener('onerror', function () {
          alert('Cannot get duration of this file.')
        }, false)
      }  
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)  
    }
}
```

You can view the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xzktcrd2/

Comment: You might not be mounting the Vue app correctly. I was able to get your code to work in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xzktcrd2/

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 thigs you can try:

**1.** Put this in the end of your function:

```
this.time = *your value*
```

**2** Call the function after your time variable and return your value in the end of your function

```
data () { 
  return {    
    time: this.checkMp3SizeAndDuration();
  }
}, 

checkMp3SizeAndDuration () {  

  const files = document.getElementById('file').files
  const file = files[0] 
  const reader = new FileReader()
  const audio = document.createElement('audio')
 
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    audio.src = e.target.result 
    let time = '' 
    audio.onloadedmetadata = () => {
      const seconds  = audio.duration
      const duration = moment.duration(seconds, 'seconds') 
      const hours = duration.hours()
      if (hours > 0) { time = `${hours}:` } 
      time = `${ duration.minutes()  }:${duration.seconds()}`  
      console.log(time) <-- Example time log: 3:51
      this.time = time // Don't work here..
    } 
    audio.addEventListener('onerror', function () {
      alert('Cannot get duration of this file.')
    }, false)
  }  
  reader.readAsDataURL(file) 

  return *your value*
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, is not working as you mentioned. i have errors vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null" on line: time: this.checkMp3SizeAndDuration() and even the return of time at the end of function is not working

Comment: Can you maybe put this in a jsfiddle so we can debug it?

Comment: sure, i will make a jsfiddle  now

Comment: Thank you. Just comment it here after u created it.

Comment: I added a console log in the function which gets called on button click but the function never gets called, even when i click the button

`submitAudioFile () {
    console.log("test")
    this.checkMp3SizeAndDuration()
      const formData = new FormData() 
      formData.append('file', this.file) 
    }`